# finding n in binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A player tosses a coin $2n$ times. The probability of head is $0.48$. 
The player wins if he gets head more than $n$ times. But he can choose the number $n$ before the game. What $n$ should he choose to increase the probability of winning, and what will be the probability?

Does someone have ideas?

As I understand it is a binomial distribution, and we need to find $n$ to maximize 
$$\operatorname{Pr}(n<X\le 2n) = \sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}p^{k}q^{2n-k}$$

but this sum is not differentiable.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: As I understand it is a binomial distribution, and we need to find n to maximize Pr(n<X<=2n)

Comment: A spreadsheet says either $12$ or $13$ would work. That's larger than I would have guessed.

Comment: The Student T distribution might be helpful here (the sample size is too small to use the normal approximation, which yields the (incorrect) result that the size of n is irrelevant)